# Bash execute multiple command to a remote server on EOF

Tags: bash, docker, openstack, eof

I try from my terminal, to execute on remote server a openstack command to a docker. The purpose is to get the id of openstack project.

when condition is true, I want to get id, but the script below failed to get id. I don't know if I can execute if condition to EOF statement

```
ret="$(ssh -qT root@server << EOF
  docker exec openstack bash -c ". adminrc &&
  if [ false ]; then  openstack project create p_ops &>/dev/null
  else :
  fi
  id_u=$(openstack user show u_ops | grep " id" | cut -d "|" -f3 | xargs)
  openstack role add SwiftOperator --project p_ops --user $id_u
  id_p=$(openstack project show p_ops | grep " id" | cut -d "|" -f3|xargs)
  echo "$id_p""
EOF
)"
```

I get the output :

```
Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
usage: openstack role add [-h]
                          [--system <system> | --domain <domain> | --project <project>]
                          [--user <user> | --group <group>]
                          [--group-domain <group-domain>]
                          [--project-domain <project-domain>]
                          [--user-domain <user-domain>] [--inherited]
                          [--role-domain <role-domain>]
                          <role>
openstack role add: error: argument --user: expected one argument
```

I desired the id of project :

```
echo $id_p
faafe2044c4235ac648faaceae5d1a3bf2a8f7a8ca8a765f5a9621a5e53d9162
```

Comment: `$()` is executed on your local machine before the SSH connection is established.

Comment: Same with the environment variables `$id_u` and `$id_p`.  I'd suggest breaking this into two or three different pieces – make the script be a script, `scp` it to the remote machine, then run it – rather than trying to escape and fit everything into a single command.  This seems like a little more of a shell-scripting or system-administration question than programming-related, though.

Comment: Your quotes are messed up, you should backslash `"` inside other `"`.  You can check your syntax at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of nested quotes which are giving you problems.

Instead of the complex sentence:

```
openstack user show u_ops | grep " id" | cut -d "|" -f3 | xargs
```

you can just write:

```
openstack user show -f value -c id
```

```sh
ret=$(ssh -qT root@server << EOF
  docker exec openstack bash -c ". adminrc &&
  if [ false ]; then openstack project create p_ops &>/dev/null
  else :
  fi
  id_u=$(openstack user show -f value -c id u_ops)
  openstack role add SwiftOperator --project p_ops --user $id_u
  id_p=$(openstack project show -f value -c id p_ops)
  echo $id_p"
EOF
)
```